# Inviting repeatedly friends

Tags: facebook, sdk, unity-game-engine, facebook-invite

When using the [FB.AppRequest](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.Apprequest) method of the [Facebook SDK for Unity](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity) without defining a list of recipients, users are prompted to send requests to their friends.

On the `Facebook canvas` a list of all user friends is being prompted but on both `iOS` and `Android` platforms a repeatedly list of few friends is displayed. Although there is a search bar at the top where users can find specific friends to request, is there a way to display different friends inside of the prompt whenever it is opened on a mobile device?

[image]

Most of the API parameters are currently `not supported for mobile devices` (FacebookSDK-140401.unitypackage).

Answer (score 0):

Apprequest parameters can be used :

> Parameter : to
>
> Type : IEnumerable
>
> Desc : A list of Facebook
>   IDs to which to send the request none - the sender will be shown a
>   dialog allowing him/her to choose the recipients